# Expand & expand appearance in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Can anyone please explain me the difference between expand & expand appearance in illustrator ?

Comment: I haven't noticed there are two "Expand" menus in Illustrator! :'D I just whizz through those options :'p
I only really choose between "Expand/Appearance" vs. "Flatten Transparency". I prefer Flatten Transparency. I dunno the difference either yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a software question that can be answered by just reading the Illustrator user guide https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/user-guide.html

Answer (score 3):

When you **Expand Appearance**, the stuff inside your Appearance Panel will get turned into individual paths or raster objects. For example, a shape of black color with a new fill of red color and a drop-shadow applied to it in the appearance panel will turn into one black shape, one red shape and one image block which contains the rasterized drop shadow.

When you **Expand**, the same kind of thing (relatively speaking) happens to the artwork that is not concerning the items in the appearance panel. For example, you can do Expand to a shape filled with a gradient and it will become a series of shapes each filled with a specific color at that point of the gradient, depending on how many steps you specified in the Expand dialog in the section about gradients. Likewise you can do Expand to a Live-Paint object, which 'freezes' the live paint by turning each live-paint section into its own separate vector path.